# How to check if a string contains a specific number

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm making a power system for my Discord bot but I have a little issue.
Here is my code

```js
  const powerPossibilities = "0" || "1" || "2" || "3" || "4" || "5";

  let powertoset = args[1];

  if (powertoset != powerPossibilities)
    return message.reply("Invalid number");
```

I want the user's power to be set on 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5 and nothing else.
So I want to check if my `args[1]` contains one of these numbers and my code didn't work.

I tried to put only the "1" on my `powerPossibilities` and it works, so the problem isn't the `args`. I'm just not sure about how to set the list of possibilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies with the syntax of your `powerPossibilities` declaration.

If you say `const val = foo || bar`, then `val` will be `foo`, unless `foo` is undefined, then `val` will be `bar`. You want something different.

---

You can implement it as follows by putting the `powerPossibilities` in an `array`:

```
const powerPossibilities = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];
```

Then check it like this:

```
if (!powerPossibilities.includes(powertoset)) {
  return message.reply("Invalid number");
}
```